# Styles & Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook, newsletter

I have some problems with Outlook on Windows 10 (I don't know for the older ones).
I am aware of the CSS compatibility problems on newsletters but I am not making any progress.

My inline styles work.
The ones in class too.
But not those with a **succession of classes** or tags.

Example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      /* WORKS */
      .title {
        color: green;
      }

      /* DOESN'T WORK */
      .news .title {
        color: red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="news">
        <td class="title">
          My title.
        </td>
      </tr>
    <tbody>
  </table>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Styling won't work in outlook 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310609/css-styling-wont-work-in-outlook-2010)

Comment: Found this Looks like what your'e looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17623120/outlook-com-how-to-target-css-at-a-specific-class

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, CSS support in emails is very limited so you have to add the attributes you want in another class or inline in the tag directly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .title {
        color: green;
      }

      .news-title {
        color: red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="news">
        <td class="news-title">
          My title.
        </td>
      </tr>
    <tbody>
  </table>
</html>
```

Comment: It is a partial solution but it does not completely meet my needs unfortunately.

Because the goal is to be able to apply a style to all the titles of a section for example.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to apply a specific class for each of your titles.