# Rendering HTML emails depending which client opens it

Tags: html, css, html-email

HTML emails are a fickle bunch.  My problem lies with superscripting.

My code is required to work in certain desktop clients:

- Outlook 2000
- Outlook 2003
- Outlook 2007
- Outlook 2010

As well as in certain web-based email clients (Firefox, Chrome, Explorer):

- Gmail
- Yahoo
- AOL
- Internet Explorer 7 browser (lol)

Currently the best cross-browser code I've come across is:

`<sup style="font-size:11px; line-height:0; vertical-align:3px;">`

This works wonderful in everything except  Outlook 2007 and 2010 where the font-size is shrunk to become almost non-legible.  Other code such as:

`<sup style="position:relative; vertical-align:baseline; bottom:4px;">`

This code works great in everything, except Gmail which strips out the positioning causing the superscript to sit on the baseline.

After trying several dozens different combinations of styling the above 2 are the ones the provide the most consistent font size and line height.

**The Question**

Is there some snippet of code I can place in the head to tell the email to use a certain code or class depending on which client the email is opened in?  I know Gmail prefers inline styling over classes so perhaps I could apply the Gmail pretty code inline, but if it's opened outside of Gmail something will cancel out the inline styling and fall back on a class.

Comment: As Far I know for email we must use inline css only.

Comment: Classes work in some clients, not all (like Gmail).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can target Outlook specifically with conditional comments](http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/outlook-conditional-css/):

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
    /* Your Outlook-specific CSS goes here. */
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking of, hopefully this works, trying it now.

Comment: @TimothyAdams Mailchimp are pretty reliable, and their blog is full of useful tricks like this. Another great resource for the endless fickleness (good description) of HTML email is the [HTML email boilerplate project](http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/).

Comment: I'll accept this because it deals with how I asked the question, but I solved my problem differently.

Comment: @TimothyAdams how did you do it in the end? `#outlook /* actual selector */ { /* properties */ }`?

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of mso tags or the style tag.

[mso Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861336/outlook-2007-to-2013-displaying-device-media-queries/16861923#16861923) will target only Outlook or specific versions of Outlook, while Gmail will not render anything from the style tag.

I would style it inline for gmail then in the style tag use `!important` to overwrite the inline declarations. Use the mso conditional tags if you want to declare multiple styles in the style tag for the rest of the email clients that are not Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest using a utility like [premailer](http://premailer.dialect.ca/) in situations like this. It will automatically inline css classes, and perform other optimizations that will help with cross-client issues. There's even an [api](http://premailer.dialect.ca/api) to automate the process if you do this sort of thing regularly.

Comment: It's not an issue of inline-css, it's a matter of code rendering differently in older/newer versions of Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue without using a conditional statement and I feel it's worth sharing in case other people deal with the same issues.

I took my original `<sup>` and swapped it with a `<span>`

So creating a `<sup>`-esque look in everything without any variation you should use the following for superscripts:

`<span style="font-size:85%; line-height:0; vertical-align:3px;"></span>`

This was tested in all the above clients and everything looked identical.