# Marketo ESP overwriting or "autocorrecting" <![if !mso]> to <!-- [if !mso] -->

Tags: outlook, html-email, marketo

I don't know if anyone on here uses Marketo as an ESP, and I'm not even sure if this is the right place to ask this type of question.

I'm trying to target Outlook in my HTML emails. No matter how I enter the code into marketo (template, Replace HTML, WYSIWYG HTML editor) the code is always auto corrected.

It changes `<![if !mso]>` to `<!-- [if !mso] -->`

I think you can see the problem here. Marketo sees the `<!` and thinks I'm trying to make a comment so it autocorrects, but the auto correct essentially renders my code invisible.

Anyone know a work around for this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<!--[if !mso]><!-->`? ([related link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861336/outlook-2007-to-2013-displaying-device-media-queries/16861923#16861923))

Comment: Thank you! That solved it. I was trying to incorporate the code from emailbtn.net ... I'll have to let him know about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the revised code (edited from [emailbtn.net](http://emailbtn.net)) that solved my ESP problem:

`<div><!--[if mso]> <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://buttonlinkhere/" style="height:44px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:200px;" arcsize="50%" stroke="f" fill="t"> <v:fill type="tile" src="http://parata.com/email-images/rx/btn-big-44.png" color="#f06609" /> <w:anchorlock /> <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:normal;" _mce_style="color: #ffffff; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal;">Microsoft Outlook</center> </v:roundrect> <![endif]--><!--[if !mso]><!--><a style="background-color: #f06609; background-image: url(http://parata.com/email-images/rx/btn-big-44.png); border-radius: 22px; color: #ffffff; display: inline-block; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 44px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; width: 200px;" href="http://buttonlinkhere/">Not Microsoft Outlook</a><!--<![endif]--></div>`

Comment: I need to append this to add that this version of code renders the button invisible on outlook.com so not a complete solution, but better than what I had before.