# Can I detect outlook client and change styles of my html email?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I am composing html email.

I know from here:http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/#css-com_1 that Outlook does not support background color but other clients does. I have nice green bg image and white text on it. But in outlook I see nothing - white text on white background with no background image.

Can I detect email client, and if it is Outlook, then change color style of my text from white to black, for example?

Things could be simplified, if I could render image with text and put image only, but I have to put links in text. Yes, I can use map/area, but this doesn't work on several important web email clients (freemail.ukr.net for me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can [target only Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861336/outlook-2007-to-2013-displaying-device-media-queries/16861923#16861923) using conditional CSS statements

But a better approach is to get it to actually work in Outlook. In html email it is best to declare your background color in a table like this:

```
<table bgcolor="#007700">...
```

Needs to be the 6-digit hex code for full client support.

For background images, check out [emailbg.net](http://emailbg.net/) for the only method where you can set a background image to a page element. (There is another non-VML way to do it that only [works in the body tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970143/how-make-background-image-on-newsletter-in-outlook/13259519#13259519))

Answer (score -1):

Email client communications with the email-server does not work the same way as browser communication does. So this can't be done.

You're best bet would be to link to a webpage at the very top of the page. Something that says **Can't View This Email? Click Here to view it in your browser.**

Comment: Conditional rendering need have no knowledge of a "server".  Outlook Express for instance identifies as IE,  although it is now frozen at IE7. You can use conditional comments accordingly....